# I can't delete google compute instance in "console"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I use node managed vm on google app engine. After I delete google compute instance at console.cloud.google.com , I see instance created automatically in "Operations". (This happens before, I used to delete instances at appengine.google.com which moved to "console" now.) How this happened? And How can I delete it?

Comment: do you have any deployed version? in App Engine Versions page

Comment: I have only one deployed version in App engine version page. And one instance running at compute engine / vm instances. I delete instance from there. But after deletetion, instances were recreated.

Comment: you should delete deployed version itself, or instance will be recreated

Comment: I can not delete the version itself, because it is the only version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete deployed version for Flexible VM. Since it's only one version, you have to deploy another one, for standard vm.

Most simple solution would be to deploy an empty version, w/o any code, just one static file. To do that create following `app.yaml`:

```
module: default
runtime: python27
api_version: '1.0'
threadsafe: true
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: index.html
    upload: index.html
resources:
  cpu: 0.1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

put an empty `index.html` in same dir. And deploy it using:

```
gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
```

After this, you'll be able to route all traffic to this dummy version, and then delete previous version deployed for Flexible VM.

Comment: I have to keep at least one instance running?

Comment: there should be at least one version, which will be running

Comment: Also, every deployed Flexible VM version will always have a running instance, even it doesn't have any traffic routed to this version. I mean _an instance_ for _every version_, even if this version is unused. That's the difference with sandboxed vm

Answer (score 10):

When the instance can not be deleted it is because, either when creating an instance the protection against the deletion was checked or because after creating an instance we activated the protection from Gcloud with the following command:

> $ gcloud compute instances update < INSTANCE_PATH> --deletion-protection

*Sample of Instance path:* `projects/your-project-265315/zones/us-central1-a/instances/your-instance-v3`

### Solution:

Active Google Cloud Shell:

**Precondition:**

Request permission for the user to access the machine (regardless of the SSH connection to the instance) to avoid *403: Insufficient Permission*.

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

---

If the deletion of the instance is protected, eliminate the protection.

```
$ gcloud compute instances update <INSTANCE_PATH> --no-deletion-protection
```

Then we delete the instance by selecting the zone correctly.

```
$ gcloud compute instances delete <instance-path>
```

GL

- [Preventing accidental vm deletion](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion)
- [Auth login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49587145/5279996)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the module from your app description. Otherwise App Engine will keep spinning new instances in accordance with the scale settings in your module description.