# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource: - Insufficient Permission

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I am having trouble working through the Compute Engine Quickstart: Build a to-do app with a MongoDB tutorial. (edit: I am running the tutorial from within the compute engine console; i.e. https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?project=&tutorial=compute_quickstart)

I SSH into the backend instance. I enter the "gcloud compute" command as copied from the tutorial. I am prompted to enter a passphrase. The following is returned:

```
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.

WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.

WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.

WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 

Enter same passphrase again: 

Your identification has been saved in

...

<< Identifying detail ommitted >>

...

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
 - Insufficient Permission**
```

I had run through this stage of the tutorial on a previous occasion with no problems. 
I am working from a Windows 10 PC with the google-cloud-sdk installed. I am using google chrome. I have tried in both regular and incognito modes.

Any help or advice greatfully received!

- DaveDub

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks like the attempt to SSH is recognising the instance in your project, but the user doesn't have the required permissions to access the machine.

Have you tried running:

```
gcloud auth login
```

and completing the web-based authorization to ensure you are attempting to access the machine as the correct (authenticated) user? This process ensures the Cloud SDK you are running inherits the permissions of the user specified in the web-based authorisation. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) for more information on this.

It's also worth adding the link to the tutorial you are following to your question.

Comment: it opens up with a link that goes to get a verification code. select the account and get the  verification code and paste it. then enter.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the accepted answer, be sure you are in the correct gcloud project

```
gcloud projects list
```

Then

```
gcloud config set project <your-project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this for yet another reason. Google has always had poor handling of multi-user auth conflicts with their business products. Whatever you sign into a clean chrome session with 'first' gets a 'special', invisible role. I've noticed with gsuite that I get 'forced' into that first user when I try to access the admin panel, and the only way to escape is to make sure that whatever google user I use for the gsuite admin is 'first', or open an incognito window. I've seen this bug for years, can't believe it still exists.

Anyways, I ran into a similar issue. Somehow I was the wrong google user, so the link I got when copy/pasting out of 'connect with gcloud command' was implying wrong google user. Only noticed later when I just gave up and used the terminal that I was not my normal user... So, might look into that.